# Django: Trying to understand the syntax of accessing request.session[SESSION_KEY]

Tags: python, django

I am trying to undestand the syntax of `request.session[SESSION_KEY]` in `django/contrib/auth/__init__.py`

The following are the details:

```
DJANGO FILENAME: django/contrib/auth/__init__.py

SESSION_KEY = '_auth_user_id'

def _get_user_session_key(request):
    return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
```

When i was debugging i check the the properties of `request.session` using `dir(request.session)` and later using `json.dumps()`

I found the following properties:

```
   "_SessionBase__not_given": "<object object at 0x7fdec4d70160>",
    "_SessionBase__session_key": "soiceej5uzukby0oef92woo0n47jiph4",
    "__dict__": {
        "_SessionBase__session_key": "soiceej5uzukby0oef92woo0n47jiph4",
        "_session_cache": {
            "_auth_user_backend": "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
            "_auth_user_hash": "6b39441cc03a5d82c9fb9b8782c7b231b6d55924",
            "_auth_user_id": "6",
            "jwt_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InNpbWhhcnVwYS5ybnNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiT1RQIjoiNTQ1ODI2IiwiY3JlYXRpb25fdGltZSI6IjIwMjAtMDEtMDlUMDU6MzM6MjMuNDAwMTc0KzAwOjAwIn0.SYDED2D5KqhZwboxGmTj9TtdSyIoGQaHBaCGRtms4uo"
        },
        "accessed": true,
        "model": "<class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>",
        "modified": false,
        "serializer": "<class 'django.core.signing.JSONSerializer'>"
    },
    "__doc__": "\n    Implement database session store.\n    ",
    "__module__": "django.contrib.sessions.backends.db",
    "__weakref__": null,
    "_session": {
        "_auth_user_backend": "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
        "_auth_user_hash": "6b39441cc03a5d82c9fb9b8782c7b231b6d55924",
        "_auth_user_id": "6",
        "jwt_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InNpbWhhcnVwYS5ybnNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiT1RQIjoiNTQ1ODI2IiwiY3JlYXRpb25fdGltZSI6IjIwMjAtMDEtMDlUMDU6MzM6MjMuNDAwMTc0KzAwOjAwIn0.SYDED2D5KqhZwboxGmTj9TtdSyIoGQaHBaCGRtms4uo"
    },
    "_session_cache": {
        "_auth_user_backend": "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
        "_auth_user_hash": "6b39441cc03a5d82c9fb9b8782c7b231b6d55924",
        "_auth_user_id": "6",
        "jwt_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InNpbWhhcnVwYS5ybnNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiT1RQIjoiNTQ1ODI2IiwiY3JlYXRpb25fdGltZSI6IjIwMjAtMDEtMDlUMDU6MzM6MjMuNDAwMTc0KzAwOjAwIn0.SYDED2D5KqhZwboxGmTj9TtdSyIoGQaHBaCGRtms4uo"
    },
    "_session_key": "soiceej5uzukby0oef92woo0n47jiph4",
    "TEST_COOKIE_NAME": "testcookie",
    "TEST_COOKIE_VALUE": "worked",
    "accessed": true,
    "modified": false,
    "session_key": "soiceej5uzukby0oef92woo0n47jiph4"
```

Then how does `request.session['_auth_user_id']` work

As per my understanding from its properties it should be

```
request.session._session_cache['_auth_user_id']  OR

request.session.__dict__['_session_cache']['_auth_user_id']
```

Comment: The `SessionBase` (the object of a `request.session`), has a `__getitem__` method, that implements the subscripting syntax: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L56

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) for more information on how to emulate a `dict` (a "container") type in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`request.session`** item [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.session) is a [**`SessionBase`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase) object. The `SessionBase` class implements a dictionary-like object with caching and lazy loading to avoid loading the session variables if this is not necessary.

If we take a look at the implementation of [**`SessionBase`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L38-L361) we see that it implements a [**`__getitem__`** method [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) to implement subscripting syntax. This method is implemented as:

> ```
>     def __getitem__(self, key):
>         if key == LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY:
>             warnings.warn(
>                 'The user language will no longer be stored in '
>                 'request.session in Django 4.0. Read it from '
>                 'request.COOKIES[settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME] instead.',
>                 RemovedInDjango40Warning, stacklevel=2,
>             )
>         return self._session[key]
> ```

It thus boild down to fetching the key from `self._session`. The `_session` is a property that is implemented as:

> ```
>     def _get_session(self, no_load=False):
>         """
>         Lazily load session from storage (unless "no_load" is True, when only
>         an empty dict is stored) and store it in the current instance.
>         """
>         self.accessed = True
>         try:
>             return self._session_cache
>         except AttributeError:
>             if self.session_key is None or no_load:
>                 self._session_cache = {}
>             else:
>                 self._session_cache = self.load()
>         return self._session_cache
>
>     _session = property(_get_session)
> ```

It thus will set the `.accessed` attribute to `True`, then return the `self._session_cache` if is *already* loaded. If not, it will load the session cache. The loading of the session cache is *backend-dependent*. Indeed, it depends on what backend you use: you can use a cache, a database, a file system, or cookies. For more information, consult the [documentation on *Configuring the session engine*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine).

Comment: Is it that on how one defines  `__getitem__` the `['some-key']` works in python. Like i have an object `a = {"key1": value1,"key2": value2,}` then `a["key1"]` gives `value1`. So where can i define `__getitem__`

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: `x[y]` boils down to `x.__getitem__(y)`, it is *syntactical sugar*, so yes.

Comment: just a general question How to define `__getitem__` for a simple object like `a = {"key1": value1,"key2": value2,}`

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: this is a dictionary, and its implementation is defined in the interpreter. For example for CPython https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L2098 It is then linked in the `mapp_methods`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L3193

Comment: Thank you. But dont you think using brackets `[ ]` is confusing rather then `__getitem__`  so that one can go and check the code.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: the idea is to make programs that are "clean" (well written). I agree that it requires some knowledge to understand what is going on behind the curtain. But for a dictionary, etc. it does not matter much, since one can pretend that `x[y]` is something special. Only later programms the realize it is just another method.